# MySQL complex ORDER BY issue

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a complicated ordering issue in my query.

**Raw, Unordered Data:**

```
+------+--------+-----------+
| id   | job_id | action_id |
+------+--------+-----------+
|    1 |      2 |         1 |  
|    2 |      2 |         2 |  
|    3 |      1 |         1 |  
|    4 |      2 |         3 |  
|    5 |      4 |         1 |  
|    6 |      1 |         2 |  
|    7 |      3 |         1 |  
|    8 |      3 |         2 |  
|    9 |      4 |         2 |  
+------+--------+-----------+
```

**Required Ordering:**

```
+------+--------+-----------+
| id   | job_id | action_id |
+------+--------+-----------+
|    7 |      3 |         1 |  
|    8 |      3 |         2 |  
|      |        |           |    * blank lines added for clarity,
|    5 |      4 |         1 |      not desired in actual data
|    9 |      4 |         2 |  
|      |        |           | 
|    3 |      1 |         1 |  
|    6 |      1 |         2 |  
|      |        |           | 
|    1 |      2 |         1 |  
|    2 |      2 |         2 |  
|    4 |      2 |         3 |  
+------+--------+-----------+
```

The theory behind this ordering:

- the largest id is the most recently added entry
- the most recent id with action_id of 1
- followed by the entries with ascending action_ids that have the same job_id
- then the next most recent action_id of 1
- ad infinitum

EDIT: I'm not able to add columns to the table in order to aid in sorting, as I've seen in some other solutions to ordering questions.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best shot is this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
    ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(job_id,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(job_id ORDER BY ID DESC) 
         FROM tbl WHERE action_id = 1));
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Bonus points for getting it all done inside the `ORDER BY` as well!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do it easily, What do you think of the following code :

```
select c.id, c.job_id, c.action_id
  from (select a.id, a.job_id, a.action_id, min(b.id) as related_id
          from myTable a 
          inner join myTable b
             on a.job_id=b.job_id 
         group by a.job_id) c
 group by c.id
 order by c.related_id desc, c.action_id
```

Comment: forgot some reference to the table in the subquery.